# Lot's Wife: The Salt Lady

Tags: names, vayera

What was the name of Lot's wife?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Iris
2. Idus
3. Melach

A summary of why she got the name from the Yalkut Reuvani with the Pirush of Rabenu Ephraim. The Poor would ask for Lechem (bread), and she would give them Melach (salt). So the Poor people davened that she that should become a pillar of salt. Hashem listened to their prayers. She answered "Amen" too, she lacked Chemlah (compassion), which means Rachmanus, so she was turned into Melach.

*Summary: The poor asked for לחם, she had no 
חמל, so she became a Pillar of מלח.*

Comment: That reminds me what did Lot say when his wife turned to Salt Yechi Hamelech and that reminds me why did Moshe Break The Luchos if you can break the rules so can I and that remind me what did Moshe say when he saw the Egel They think its a Holy Cow!!!

Comment: The second part is connected to a real _chazal_.