# What was the name of Rivka's mother?

Tags: names, parashat-chaye-sara, imahot-matriarch-mothers

Unnamed women in the Torah, so far: Noach's wife-Naama, Yishmoel's wife-Riva, Lot's wife-Iris, any suggestions for Rivka's mother? she is mentioned many times in this weeks sedra but not by name

Comment: I have another but a missing dad -- my great uncle put money out there for anyone who could find the name of Naomi's father in megillat rut (she is apparently called "avi na'ami" but how could that be his name before his child was born?)

Comment: @Dan kind of the opposite of אבנר בנ נר

Comment: Lots wifes name was Irit, not Adina - see Baal HaTurim http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14020&st=&pgnum=245

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/lots-wife-the-salt-lady

Comment: Yishmaels wifes name was Riva - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38765&hilite=9ea311db-3e9e-4262-90dd-09f70ea5d318&st=%u05d0%u05e9%u05ea+%u05d9%u05e9%u05de%u05e2%u05d0%u05dc

Comment: Sorry Iris was indeed Lot's wife, Ramban posuk 17 ch 19.

Comment: Lovon's wife was Adina http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4549/what-was-the-name-of-rachel-and-leahs-mother

Comment: Yishmael's second wife was called Malchis and Noach's wife is (only according to Sefer HaYuvlim, Emzara)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky in his Sefer טעמא דקרא brings down (on Parshash Chayei Sarah) that Rivka's mothers name was Devorah, indeed the same Devorah that the Torah referres to as the  מינקת. His source is [Midrash Agadah Parshas Vayishlach](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33177&st=&pgnum=101&hilite=)!

Comment: Very good! +1..

Comment: @GershonGold Thanks [and for the source]! :-) It happens to be an extremely useful Sefer