# Who was Naomi's Father?

Tags: names, book-of-ruth

Inspired by this [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22153/what-was-the-name-of-rivkas-mother/22163#comment50402_22153) here what information do we have on Naomi's father (from Megillas Rus)? Apparently  his name was Avi-Naomi but was that his real name before Naomi was born? Who was his father?

Comment: How do we know his name was Avi-Naomi?

Comment: @DoubleAA see edit

Comment: Okay... how, then, it is apparent?

Comment: @msh210 see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22164/who-was-naomis-father/22165#comment50440_22165

Comment: yehuda, I see he's called _avi Naomi_, but I don't understand why you say that's his name.

Comment: @msh210 When I say name it refers to the name people referred to him by as is clear in my question `but was that his real name before Naomi was born`.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37840

Answer (score 5):

Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky in his Sefer טעמא דקרא brings down that from the [Gemoro Bava Basra 91a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9585&st=&pgnum=185) that he was the son of Nachshon ben Aminadav ( and a brother of Elimelech).

Comment: the gemara here is where he is called "avi naami" and nothing more. is there a place in the chumash which lists all the sons of nachshon so his identity can be deduced via process of elimination?

Comment: @Dan The only child of Nachshon mentioned in Tanach is Salma/Salmah/Salmon (presumably all the same person) in Ruth 4 and I Chronicles 2

Comment: Elimelech, Tov and Salman were all sons of Nachshon. As Nachshon died in the 2nd year in the wilderness, if the story happened around the time of Ivtzan then they were all very very old. If it happened at the time of Ehud they were still old but not quite as old. But Oved must have lived a very long time..