# Who was Naomi's mother?

Tags: family-members, genealogy, book-of-ruth

I would like to know the genealogy of Naomi the mother in law of Rus. Specifically, who was her mother?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22164/who-was-naomis-father

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that this information is available? Why do you want to know?